# Using a data access DLL with HTML forms

Tags: c#, mysql, html, dll, webforms

I've agreed to help out a friend with getting their website off the ground. Previously, someone else helped out by writing a data access layer dll in C#, which I luckily have access to the code. Not any means to change and recompile though, as C# has never been one of my primary languages.

Problem is, I have no idea how I'm supposed to call it. In HTML, I tried out

`<form action='dll/MyLib.dll' method='GET'>'`

But I've no understanding how to call a specific function out of the DLL nor how to pass parameters. I'm not even sure if I managed to load it. For example, if I have an HTML form to add a new user to a MySQL database, I want to call the DLL's connection and addUser functions.

I found a 2005 article on DLLs and HTML, but trying out their code doesn't seem to work in actual practice:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s0d4hwc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Anyone with any experience in this? I'm tempted to rewrite the DLL in a PHP script...

Comment: Calling DLL directly from HTML? Scary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it wrong. While there "may" be a way to do what you're saying, there are much MUCH better/easier ways to go about this, one of which is using an IDE that understands .NET and can work with your C# code. I would recommend getting [Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions) or [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) if you can't afford VS2010 and learning how [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/) works.

It may take longer in the short run than whatever hacks people may or may not suggest here, but it will be a huge payoff in the long run, and who knows, maybe you'll really like programming in it :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not call dll from html, please.

If you already have C#-related project, try ASP .NET.